# Closure stored in class property

Tags: swift

Don't understand why compiler make the error on this code snippet

```
class Addr {

    var num: Int = 0
    lazy var increment: (Int) -> () = {[unowned self] value in
        self.num += value
        print(self.num)
    }
    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}

do {
    let object = Addr().increment(5) // ERROR
}
```

Of course, i can change in capture list [unowned self] to [weak self] but I try to understand why this code not working. Why is the obeject is deinit before the call of the property. Will be thanked for the advanced explanation of this mechanism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that since you are not storing a reference to the `Addr` object, it gets deallocated immediately, even before `increment` would be called on it.

Storing `Addr` in a variable and then calling `increment` on the variable solves the issue.

```
let object = Addr()
object.increment(5)
```

Comment: A do block is useful to test the scope of variables. Without it, the deinit method would not be called (in a command line application)

Comment: @MartinR I didn't think about that, thanks for clearing that up, updated my answer :)